# Elasticsearch prioritize one query over another

Tags: php, html, elasticsearch

I've a PHP script which run two queries against Elasticsearch and echo the results on a PHP/HTML page. The two queries search for the same text in the same fields, but one has an AND operator and the other uses an OR operator.

The results I recieve from the AND operator is the ones I want to appear first. The results from the OR operator should also appear but they should appear after the first results. This does not seem to happen with how the script is right now.

The Script:

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['REDACTED:9200'])->build();
    $es = $client;

    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $query = $es->search([
            'index' => 'rss',
            'size' => '30',
            'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'simple_query_string' => [
                    'fields' => ["message","title"],
                    'query' => "$q",
                    'default_operator' => 'and',
                    'minimum_should_match' => '100%'
                ],
                'simple_query_string' => [
                    'fields' => ["message","title"],
                    'query' => "$q",
                    'default_operator' => 'or',
                    'minimum_should_match' => '80%'
                ]
            ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
    if($query['hits']['max_score'] >=1 ) {
        $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
    }

    ?>
   <!doctype html> 
    <html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Søkemotor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="img/DigRevLogo3.png" alt="Logo" width="200" height="50" class="img">
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <form action="index.php" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="search_form">
                <label><input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Søk her"></label>
                <label><input type="submit" value="Søk" name="s"></label>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php
        $noresult = "Ingen resultat på søket av $q.";
        $i = 0;
        if(isset($results)) {
            foreach($results as $r) { ?>
                <div class="result">
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="<?php echo $r['_source']['link']; ?>"><?php echo $r['_source']['title'];?></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="message">
                        <br>
                        <?php echo $r['_source']['message'];?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="published">
                        <br>
                        <?php echo $r['_source']['published'];?>            
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="noresult">
                <?php 
            }
        }
        else echo "<CENTER>$noresult</CENTER>"; ?>
                </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My results now if my query is "Apple Orange" appears something like this:

```
RESULT 1: Apple Apple
RESULT 2: Apple Orange
RESULT 3: Apple Apple Apple
RESULT 4: Orange
```

What I want to appear is something like this:

```
RESULT 1: Apple Orange
RESULT 2: Apple Apple Apple
RESULT 3: Apple Apple
RESULT 4: Orange
```

How could I do this? I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3 installed on Debian 9. PHP version is 7.2. I'll provide if there is any other information that can be useful but I'm not sure what is required.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain both search results in a single query?

Comment: @AhmedNumaan Yes I want to obtain both search result, I just want the results of the first search to appear first because they're the ones that contains both words (for example both apple and orange).

Comment: If you were using database query then union of the two queries would have solved your problem: `(Query with AND condition) UNION (Query with OR condition);`

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this a bit, let's reduce it to the Elasticsearch query and switch it over to a `match`, which is generally the query to get started with and then dive deeper as required:

```
DELETE fruit
PUT fruit
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  }
}
POST fruit/_doc
{
  "fruit": "Apple Apple"
}
POST fruit/_doc
{
  "fruit": "Apple Orange"
}
POST fruit/_doc
{
  "fruit": "Apple Apple Apple"
}
POST fruit/_doc
{
  "fruit": "Orange"
}
GET fruit/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "fruit": "Apple Orange"
    }
  }
}
```

The result for this is:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1.0498221,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "fruit",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "oRg6HmUBs4EUCKS4dujJ",
        "_score": 1.0498221,
        "_source": {
          "fruit": "Apple Orange"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fruit",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "oxg6HmUBs4EUCKS4d-hu",
        "_score": 0.87138504,
        "_source": {
          "fruit": "Orange"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fruit",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "ohg6HmUBs4EUCKS4d-ga",
        "_score": 0.5062483,
        "_source": {
          "fruit": "Apple Apple Apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fruit",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "oBg6HmUBs4EUCKS4duh-",
        "_score": 0.49042806,
        "_source": {
          "fruit": "Apple Apple"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For the general understanding, the score is calculated by BM25 (which is pretty similar to the old TF/IDF). Why do we get this specific order?

- The first document contains both your search terms — that makes sense.
- A document having a search term multiple times (Apple Apple Apple vs Apple) is ranked higher.
- Why is Orange ranked higher than Apple Apple Apple? Because Orange is overall rarer (appears twice in all your documents vs six times for Apple)

If you add an `explain` to your query, it will actually show you how all the scores were calculated:

```
GET fruit/_search
{
  "explain": true, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "fruit": "Apple Orange"
    }
  }
}
```

How can you change that default behavior? There are parameters in BM25 that you can tune. Read the [blog post series on BM25](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch), which describes a lot of the concepts here. But take note that this is already a pretty advanced topic.